# which one? permutation or combination?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

Let say we have a bookshelf that can fit 6 books, we want 4 computer science books and 2 physics books but computer books should be together and physics books also should be together, we have 8 computer and 6 physics book in total in how many ways we can do that?

I believe that the answer is like this:

c(8,4)*c(6,2) + c(6,2)*c(8,4)

but my instructor sloved it in this way(by p I mean permutation):

p(8,4)*p(6,2) + p(6,2)*p(8,4)

could u please tell me which one is right?

Comment: It can be hard to phrase such questions in such a way that doesn't just *give the answer (or method) away*, so I feel your pain. But you should assume that "Dynamics, then Quantum Mechanics" is different than "Quantum Mechanics, then Dynamics".

Comment: (In other words, order matters, so it's permutations.)

Comment: Thanks how did u understand that it is permutation? is there any ordering?

Comment: I cannot say with absolute certainty. I am using the assumption that *order matters* (--> permutation), which I think is reasonable because ... well... the order of books on **my bookshelf** matters to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If the order of the books matter (as in, computer science book A needs to come before computer science book B, for example), then your instructor would be right.

If they don't, then you would be right.

Comment: If the order of the book does not matter (other than the given constraint that books of the same subject should be together) then the answer would be c(8,4)*c(6,2). Unless the order of the subjects mattered, in which case the answer would be c(8,4)*c(6,2)+c(6,2)*c(8,4).